# Fix table head in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've a function that allows me to keep the THs of my table fixed despite scrolling.
In Google chrome doesn't present this problem since it works very well

[image]

But I am interested in making it work in IE11
But it looks like this:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

I'm working with:

- MVC 4
- jQuery 1.7

Table code:

```
    <div class="tableFixHead">
<table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">  
    <thead>
    <tr>   
        <th>STATUS</th>  
        <th>EMP #</th>  
        <th>TYPE</th>  
        <th>NAME</th>  
        <th>LEADERS</th>  
        <th>DEPARTMENT</th>  
        <th>TEAM / PART</th>
        <th>SERIAL</th>
        <th>FA</th>
        <th>SECURITY</th>
        <th>BRAND</th>
        <th>MODEL</th>  
        <th>YEAR</th>
        <th>MONTH</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th>DATA DESTRUCTION</th>
        <th>LOCATION</th>   
    </tr>   
  </thead>
@foreach (var item in Model) {  
    <tbody>
        <tr>  
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_STATUS)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_EMP_ASSIGN)</td>  
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_EMP_TYPE)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_EMP_ASIGN_NAME)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_EMP_LEADERTYPE)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_EMP_DEPT)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_EMP_DEPTEAM)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_SERIAL)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_FA_TAG)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_SECURITY_TAG)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_BRAND)</td>     
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_MODEL)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_YEAR)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_MONTH)</td>
            <td>$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_PRICE)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_EMP_DATA_DESTRUCTION)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HW_LOCATION)</td>  
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "LaptopInventoryEdit", new { id = item.ID})</td>         
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
}    
</table>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
var $th = $('.tableFixHead').find('thead th')
$('.tableFixHead').on('scroll', function () {
    $th.css('transform', 'translateY(' + this.scrollTop + 'px)');
    });
    });
```

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide an [mcve] of the issue

Comment: Your code works in a genuine IE11 : https://jsbin.com/wudelanane/1/edit?html,css,js,output  jsbin can be run from older IES

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks for you apport but still fail in IE11

Comment: @BlackSD ?? not mine , but i'm running win10, maybe you have win7 version ? Does the jsbin fails for you ? did you hit the button "run with js" ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I'm running Win10 Pro, when I open jsbin link in IE it has the same issue.

Comment: funny, i do not have that problem,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONmGA.jpg . Sorry i can't help :(

Comment: Let me try with the library, although with version 1.7 it always gives me errors like JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'freezeHeader'